# How to write multiple records to JSON in file on Java

Tags: java, json

I need to write multiple json in one file, the problem is that every time that inserts inserted as follows:

```
{"1":"{\"id\":\"1\"}"**}{**"2":"{\"id\":\"2\"}"**}{**"3":"{\"id\":\"3\"}"}
```

and I need the chain follows to that can be read for JSON:

```
{"1":"{\"id\":\"1\"}"**,**"2":"{\"id\":\"2\"}"**,**"3":"{\"id\":\"3\"}"}
```

my code is:

```
 public void writeMci(String mci, String nombreMci) throws Exception{

          FileReadWrite a=new FileReadWrite();     
          JSONObject vjo = new JSONObject();


          vjo.put(nombreMci, mci);


          try {

          BufferedWriter write=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\JSON.json", true));

              write.write(vjo.toString());
              write.flush();
              write.close();


          } catch (IOException e) {
            //manejar error 
          }

          System.out.print(vjo);




      }
```

Comment: It might be helpful to add the contents of `c:\\JSON.json` and point out what you expect to happen, it's not very clear what you need by reading the question...

Comment: You should make the outer file level an array (starting with `[`), then write your individual JSON components separated by `,`, then close the file with `]`.

Comment: [link] try several times and I do not, I hope you can help me, I'm new in JSON, thanks

Comment: Write `[` to the file.  Then, without closing, write your first JSON string.  Then (file still open) write `,`, then write your second JSON string, then `]`.  Then close your file.

Answer (score 1):

The line you want

```
{"1":"{\"id\":\"1\"}"**,**"2":"{\"id\":\"2\"}"**,**"3":"{\"id\":\"3\"}"}
```

isn't legal either, I assume you mean (at least) something like this:

```
{"1":"{\"id\":\"1\"}","2":"{\"id\":\"2\"}","3":"{\"id\":\"3\"}"}
```

Note that this is *not* a JSON array, it's an object with ***string*** fields respectively called 1 2 and 3 that happen to contain JSON syntaxed string values.  Although not illegal, it's highly questionable you actually want that

Now, could it be that you mean

```
{"1":{"id":"1"},"2":{"id":"2"},"3":{"id":"3"}}
```

Still an object but with ***object*** fields respectively called 1 2 and 3, where the object has just 1 field called id?  Anyways (**disclaimer**: not an org.json library user myself - see below - so not giving any guarantees wrt the accuracy of the code :) ) :

```
// Create the outer container
JSONObject outer = new JSONObject();

// Create a container for the first contained object
JSONObject inner1 = new JSONObject();
inner1.put("id",1);
// and add that to outer
outer.put("1",inner1);

// Create a container for the second contained object
JSONObject inner2 = new JSONObject();
inner2.put("id",2);
// and add to outer as well
outer.put("2",inner2);

// Create a container for the third contained object
JSONObject inner3 = new JSONObject();
inner3.put("id",3);
// and add that to outer
outer.put("3",inner3);

// at this point

outer.toString()

// should return the JSON String from my last step.
```

if you actually want it to be an array, you need to put the objects in a JSONArray, and wrap that array as a named field inside an object. The end result will look more or less like this:

```
{"data": [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]}
```

Code for the inner objects is the same as above, but there's a new layer (the array) between the inner and outer object:

```
JSONArray middle = new JSONArray();
...
middle.add(inner1);
...
middle.add(inner2);
...
middle.add(inner3);
...
outer.put("data",middle);
```

Still not sure if that's what you actually want, but I think it's a first step towards a solution.  That being said, I would recommend you to switch to a nicer JSON Java library than the one from json.org you are apparently using.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library?rq=1) for some feedback on different libraries that are available, for my projects I've been using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) since quite some time now and I'm very happy with it, but the SO question I linked to talks about several other, excellent alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You should write both objects, as below:

```
    write.write(vjo.toString());
    write.newLine();
    write.write(conb.toString());
    write.newline();
    write.flush();
    write.close();
```

Comment: AFAIK JSON at the outer level is one object that can contain multiple members.  Your proposal will create one file containing two objects, and I don't think that's legal JSON...

Comment: @ FVU is to understand JSON